# How can I separate a text file into columns, but only for specific lines?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, txt

I have a .psa file that I need manipulated, but to my knowledge the file needs to be in a .txt or .csv to manipulate using pandas. To solve this issue, I am reading the original file and writing the contents into another .txt file to which my code will apply to.

The original .psa file has text data in it, all separated by commas. I am trying to organize this data into columns and only pulling the data I need. Each line has 30+ values separated by  commas, but I only need the 3rd value to put into a column.
I will have a zip folder which needs this code to run through and do the same thing to each file within the folder. Each file will have a different store number in the title.

Example:

filename: `1 Area 2 - store 15 group.psa`

```
prod,123,456,abc,def, etc...
pla,124,uhj,jop,etc. 
prod,321,789,ghi,jkl, etc...
...
```

Expectation:
I want to only take out the third item in the lines that start with `prod` and put it into a .csv file. I want to also keep the title of the original file in another column (would be very nice if it is only the store number included on there, but not a necessity).
Ex.

| nums | store # |
| --- | --- |
| 456 | 15 |
| 789 | 15 |

Here is the code I have so far:

```
with open('1 Area 2 - store 15 group.psa','r') as firstfile, open('test.txt','a') as secondfile: 
    # read content from first file 
    for line in firstfile: 
         # append content to second file 
         secondfile.write(line)

file = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep=',', usecols=[0,1,2], header=0, names=['col 1','col 2','col 3'])
file.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

This code is able to give me the columns as output, but the rows end up including lines that don't start with prod and I have 3 columns instead of just the num column (get an error when I only do [usecols=2], so the data is still messy and I have no idea how to get the title of the original file in the second column.

Comment: `if not line.startswith("prod"): continue` where you have the `# append` comment now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do everything you want inside pandas without writing to a temporary file; just read in the first and third columns, filter on the first column value and then drop it; finally add the store number (extracted from the filename) as the second column:

```
import re

fname = '1 Area 2 - store 15 group.psa'
df = pd.read_csv(fname, usecols=[0, 2], header=None, names=['type', 'num'])
store = re.search(r'store\s+(\d+)', fname).group(1)
df = df[df['type'] == 'prod'].drop(columns='type').assign(store=store)
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
num,store
456,15
789,15
```

Comment: Thanks for that info. The columns are created in the output file, but for some reason there are no rows.

Comment: @uranis Is it possible there are other characters around 'prod' e.g. whitespace? what if you use `df[df['type'].str.contains('prod')]` instead?

Comment: There is no whitespace, but the p should be uppercase and I accounted for that. Now the weird thing is that data shows up in the 'store' column where there is the file name, but for only 93 rows. The data is over 10k+ rows. 
So the output is 2x93 with the 'num' column being blank. Weirdly when I set the usecols = 0,1 those 93 cells in the num column are filled w other numbers

Comment: Please ignore the 93 cells comment... I completely looked at the wrong file. Only issue is the blank cells

Comment: That sounds like maybe there's an extra, empty column before `num` in the data? Can you maybe paste just a few lines (redacted as necessary to protect confidentiality) from the actual input you are using into the question? That would help debug the problem.

Comment: Sure: here are 2 lines from the actual input
Prod,787896576342,3000089787,BALL LIGHT YELLOW,78990,1,2,9,0,1,...
Prod, 787877578923,3000089788,LIN LIGHT BLUE,78991,1,2,0,0,1,...
The lines continue for about 50+ commas. usecol=0,1 will include the first 12 digit number, but I'm looking to get the second value which is the 10 digit. usecol=0,5 or any other number also yields blanks.

Comment: @uranis I still get `num,store
3000089787,15
3000089788,15` for that input... I'm running Python 3.11 and pandas 2.1, what are you running?

Comment: @uranis if you look at `df` after `read_csv` are there lines with `type == 'Prod'` in there? I'm wondering if not all your lines have the same number of values in them

Comment: So I tried out the same code and just included an additional column header then dropped also. It worked! Not sure why this was the case, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Would you happen to have any idea how to run this code for a zip file? Each file within the zip will have different titles, with diff store numbers so the fname would have to adapt. What could I change that line to?

Comment: @uranis I'm glad you got it working. I'm not sure how to process files inside a zip, it's probably worth asking a new question

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it in pandas that ends with a dataframe with your exact specified column headers...

```
import pandas as pd

# Your store file
store_file = '1 Area 2 - store 15 group.psa'

# You can use pandas to read your .psa as a csv
df = pd.read_csv(store_file, usecols=[0, 2], header=None, names=['type', 'num'])
df = df[df['type'] == 'prod']

# You don't need to keep the "type" column
df.drop(columns='type', inplace=True)

# Assuming the names of your "store files" are systematically named, this should work for storing the store number...
store = store_file.split(' ')[5] 
df['store #'] = store

# Save df as file if desired...
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without Pandas, if you want.

The following reads the PSA (as a CSV, because it looks like a CSV to me) into a whole list of rows, then moves that list through a succession of list comprehensions to filter the rows by "prod", cut just the 3rd column, then append the store number.  If you have any questions about what each operation actually does you can print out the intermediate results:

```py
def process_psa(fname: str):
    m = re.search(r"store-(\d{1,2})", fname)
    assert m, f"{r"store-(\d{1,2})"} did not match {fname}"
    store_no = m.group(1)

    with open(fname, newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        rows = list(reader)


    filtered = [x for x in rows if x[0] == "prod"]

    cut = [x[2:3] for x in filtered]  # keep a slice of the 3rd field

    final = [x + [store_no] for x in cut]


    with open(f"output-{store_no}.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["nums", "store #"])
        writer.writerows(final)


for fname in glob.glob("*.psa"):
    process_psa(fname)
```

I mocked up another PSA file, which I labelled as store 23:

```
prod,654,111,abc,def,etc...
pla,834,888,uhj,jop,etc...
prod,765,523,ghi,jkl,etc...
```

Running that script with input-store-15.psa and input-store-23.psa I ended up with:

```
output-15.csv

nums,store #
456,15
789,15
```

and

```
output-23.csv

nums,store #
111,23
523,23
```